# Many-to-one relationship of two models inheriting from the same polymorphic type in sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlalchemy

I have a polymorphic base class like:

```py
class Addressable(Base):
    addressable_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    addressable_type = Column(String, nullable=False)
    addresses = relationship('Address')

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymoprhic_on': addressable_type}
```

That is used to allow child classes the ability to add any number of addresses with:

```
class Address(Base):
    # ...
    addressable_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Addressable.addressable_id')
```

As far as my (so far, limited) tests can tell, this part works. What doesn't is that two of the child classes have a many-to-one relationship with each other.

```
class CompanyLocation(Addressable):
   __mapper_args_ = {'polymprophic_identity': 'CompanyLocation'}
   company_location_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Addressable.addressable_id), primary_key=True)
   company_id = Column(CompanyId, ForeignKey('Company.company_id'), nullable=False)

class Company(Addressable):
    __mapper_args_ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'Company'}
    company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Addressable.addressable_id), primary_key=True)
    locations = relationship(CompanyLocation, foreign_keys=CompanyLocation.company_location_id,
                             backref='company')
```

When testing, if I do:

```
company = Company() 
company.addresses.append(Address(name='foo'))
location = CompanyLocation()
company.locations.append(location)
session.add(company)
session.commit()

assert company.addresses[0].name == 'foo'  # Works!
assert company.locations[0] == location
```

I get, puzzlingly:

```
E    assert <Company object at 0x119e151d0> == <CompanyLocation object at 0x117edc950>
```

Somehow `locations` holds the value of the Company itself, and not its locations. If I try to add a second location to the company, the operation fails because the entry isn't unique (which makes sense, because somehow it's using its own PK as the FK?) Likewise, `location.company` gives back the `CustomerLocation` object.

If I remove the `append` call, and explicitly add `customer = relationship('Customer', foreign_keys=customer_id, back_populates='locations')` to the `CompanyLocation` class, the resulting call to `company.locations` results in an empty list. However, doing this *does* at least fix the call to `location.company`

---

What have I done?

Underlying, we're using PostgresQL, and are using sqlalchemy 1.3.11

For context, the use case here is that our customers need to attach addresses to to corporate entities (e.g., a billing address) which may be different than their individual locations' addresses (some of which also have their own billing vs. mailing addresses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got it to work after trying several different solutions. I still don't understand why the above failed, but things worked after I used `primaryjoin` instead of `foreign_keys`, e.g.,

```
class Company:
    # . . .
    locations = relationship("CompanyLocation", back_populates='company', primaryjoin='Company.company_id == CompanyLocation.company_id')
```